# JavaScript/JSON - Get the total average of values having the same key from multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am receiving real-time responses from the back-end that contains the following JSON (almost every second):

One Array:

```
 {
"newUpdate": [ 
{
    "id": "TP", 
    "val" : 3
},
{ 
    "id": "TPE20", 
    "val" : 3
}]
 }
```

Another array (after one second or less)

```
 {
"newUpdate": [ 
{
    "id": "CRK", 
    "val" : 24
},
{ 
    "id": "TPE20", 
    "val" : 44
}]
 }
```

I am getting the above JSON almost every second knowing that each time it comes with different values and id's, and the array itself does not have a specific size.

Well, what I want to do is to get the average of the values having the same key 'id'.

For example, for the above array, the average will be for **TPE20** :

```
(3+44)/2 =23.2 (as it computes the average for the id : TPE20)
```

Then it should show it here (using JQuery for example) [Think of the real-time average value like in the stock market]

```
<div id="TPE20"></div>
```

Currently, using the below for loop, I print the JSON listed above:

```
for(var i in load.updates){
var id =     load.newUpdate[i].id;
updatesMap[id] = load.newUpdate[i].value;
var valueOfID = newUpdate[id];
}
```

The challenge is that I am receiving a lot of arrays at once (1/sec), each array contains different "id" and "val", I really don't know how I can compute the average using the way I described above!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use an object with keys representing the ids of the array objects and the values as objects containing the count, total, and average of those ids.

When you receive a new array simply update the object:

```
function updateObj(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(el) {
    var key = el.id;
    obj[key] = obj[key] || { count: 0, total: 0, avg: 0 };
    obj[key].count++;
    obj[key].total += el.val;
    obj[key].avg = obj[key].total / obj[key].count;
  });
}
```

[Here's a simulation](https://jsfiddle.net/L4wpm2ye/1/) with `setInterval` sending one array to the function each second, and then displaying the completed object in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help? It get the Average of the search term like you asked. It uses jquery $.each to iterate through the array

```js
var newdata = [
  {
    "newUpdate": [ 
      {
        "id": "TP", 
        "val" : 3
      },
      { 
        "id": "TPE20", 
        "val" : 3
      }]
  },
  {
    "newUpdate": [ 
      {
        "id": "CRK", 
        "val" : 24
      },
      { 
        "id": "TPE20", 
        "val" : 44
      }]
  }
]

function getAverage(array, term){
  var sum = 0, n = 0;
  $.each(array, function(i, item){
    n++
    var arrs = item.newUpdate
    $.each(arrs, function(d, place){
      // console.log(d)
      if (place.id == term){
        sum +=place.val 
      }


    })

  })
  return sum / n
}

document.write(getAverage(newdata, "TPE20"))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.prototype.forEach()` , create a private property at an object to store number of occasions unique property occurs within callback; pass each object individually to function in succession to maintain averages of properties at single object

```js
var a = {
  "newUpdate": [{
    "id": "TP",
    "val": 3
  }, {
    "id": "TPE20",
    "val": 3
  }]
};

var b = {
  "newUpdate": [{
    "id": "CRK",
    "val": 24
  }, {
    "id": "TPE20",
    "val": 44
  }]
}

var avg = {};

function update(update) {

  update.newUpdate.forEach(function(value, index) {
    if (!avg[value.id] || !avg.hasOwnProperty(value.id)) {
      avg["_" + value.id] = 1;
      avg[value.id] = value.val / avg["_" + value.id];
    } else {
      ++avg["_" + value.id];
      avg[value.id] += value.val;
      avg[value.id] = avg[value.id] / avg["_" + value.id];
    }

  });
  
  return avg
  
}

console.log(update(a), update(b), avg)
```